# Limit Shiny unbindAll and bindAll only to and HTML element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, r, shiny

In the Shiny site they say that *before making changes to the DOM, that is to say, add or remove inputs and outpus, you need to tell Shiny by calling* `unbindAll` and `bindAll`:

```
function modifyDom()
{          
    Shiny.unbindAll()
    insertInputsAndOutputs()
    removeOtherInputsAndOutputs()    
    Shiny.bindAll()
}
```

The thing is that my web app has 2 parts: a select on a sidebar and a main container that displays information depending on what the user chooses. And the problem is this:

1. Suppose, User has already chosen item 1, so structure 1 is displayed on the container
2. When user chooses item 2, structure 1 is deleted when `modifyDom` is called and the very last line `Shiny.bindAll()` causes that even the select of the sidebar to reinitialize, so it selects item 1 and the structre 1 is displayed again.

Therefore my question: Is there a way in Shiny **not to unbind all** objects but only the ones that exist **within a certain HTML element**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've never work with Shiny before, but according to [this link](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/shiny-discuss/czXoYWnXGe8) and searching on [its Github repo](https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=unbindall), both `unbindall` and `bindall` functions can be used in the following way too:

`unbindall(element)`

`bindall(element)`

Where `element` seems to be a DOM element (returned value from `document.getElementById` function or jQuery equivalent `$('#element')[0]`).

So you can write another function like this:

```
function modifyDomByElement (element) {
  Shiny.unbindAll(element);
  insertInputsAndOutputs();
  removeOtherInputsAndOutputs();
  Shiny.bindAll(element);
}
```

And preserve `modifyDom` function working as you post (don't forget [Single responsibility principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle)).